# Printing an incremented row index and average value in a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, average, increment

I have a 2D array of 4 tests, 5 scores a piece. I need to print the average out with which test number it belongs to. I also need the tests numbers to be 1-4 instead of 0-3.

I'm unsure of how to renumber the tests and get it to print a readable number:

```java
int[][] testScores = {
        {100, 85, 91, 75, 82}, 
        {81, 75, 68, 92, 87}, 
        {99, 71, 75, 84, 91}, 
        {97, 91, 68, 72, 83}};

for (int i = 0; i < testScores.length; i++) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < testScores[i].length; j++) {
        sum += testScores[i][j];
    }

    System.out.println("Average of Test#" + testScores[i]
            + "is " + sum / testScores[i].length);
    System.out.println();
}
```

My final output should be something like:

Test#I has an average of J where I begins at 1 and goes to 4.

I will most likely need to add more tests later on as this develops, but I'm sure I will be able to manage that once I can get this sorted. I appreciate the assistance in advance!

Comment: Just replace `testScores[i]` with `i`

Comment: That is great!  But I now need it to be 1-4 instead of 0-3.  How can I achieve that? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think I got it.  I could just add this:  ***int testNumber = i+1;
      System.out.println("Average of Test#" + testNumber + " is " + sum/testScores[i].length);
      System.out.println();***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the [`range`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range(int,int)) of row indices of this array, and for each row, put together in one [`entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#entry(K,V)) the incremented index of the row and its [`average`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#average()) value. Your code might look something like this:

```java
int[][] testScores = {
        {100, 85, 91, 75, 82},
        {81, 75, 68, 92, 87},
        {99, 71, 75, 84, 91},
        {97, 91, 68, 72, 83}};

IntStream.range(0, testScores.length)
        // Stream<Map.Entry<Integer,Double>>
        .mapToObj(i -> Map.entry(
                // number of the line of scores
                i + 1,
                // average value for this line
                Arrays.stream(testScores[i])
                        .average().orElse(0)))
        // output
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

```
1=86.6
2=80.6
3=84.0
4=82.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Per Nick's comment, `testScores[i]` needs changed to `i` and to increment the `testScores` accordingly by test number should be done this way:

```java
int testNumber = i + 1;
System.out.println("Average of Test#" + testNumber
        + " is " + sum / testScores[i].length);
System.out.println();
```